# ionic 4 Tabs navigation navigate forward

Tags: angular-router, ionic4

Does anyone have any luck on navigating to the next page in a tabs page without losing the tab bar? I didn't manage to find any working sample online.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working, just put the new page in the tabs children array. Then when navigate, the link will be '/tabs/(outlet:child2)' where the outlet is the view you wish the page push into. Good lord, there is no documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to plain navigation with tabs, it follows a `(outlet:path)` style.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
                pathMatch: 'full',
            },
            {
                path: 'home',
                outlet: 'home',
                component: HomePage
            },
            {
                path: 'contact',
                outlet: 'contact',
                component: ContactPage
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                outlet: 'settings',
                component: SettingsPage
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

I still have not figured out nesting.  Ex: /tabs/(settings:settings/about)  where about page/component is a child route for settings.

May I ask how you achieved navigating to a "next page" after a tab page?

Sources: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-4-routing-and-navigation-guide/

Comment: Using route.navigateByUrl, you can navigate to a new page, but it will be an overlay page instead of pushing a new page to the tab's navigation stack. No official documentation nor online example that i can find that do that.

Comment: I managed to get it working, just put the new page in the tabs page children array. Then when navigate, the link will be '/tabs/(outlet:child2)' where the outlet is the view you wish the page push into.